# How can I to fix a nested for?

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist

I am doing two for cycles for a list of 3 data; it stays in a loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tblView.getItems().size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < tblView.getItems().size(); j++) {
            u1 = tblView.getItems().get(i).getutilidadGeneral();
            u2 = tblView.getItems().get(j).getutilidadGeneral();

        }
    }
```

the first cycle must go through the whole list; while the second must go in front of her (n + 1) and finish just no more elements

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Did you mean `int j = i+1` ?

Comment: Could you add some info about what you're actually trying to achieve with this loop? Assuming there are no side effects to `getutilidadGeneral` you could simply write `int n = tblView.getItems().size(); if (n >= 2) { u1 = u2  = tblView.getItems().get(n-1).getutilidadGeneral();}`

Comment: I have a list of n items
my first cycle I want to run the entire row, and the next cycle n + 1;Thanks I will try;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want say `j = i+1` , because `n+1` is an error because n is the size;

```
int n = tblView.getItems().size();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            u1 = tblView.getItems().get(i).getutilidadGeneral();
            u2 = tblView.getItems().get(j).getutilidadGeneral();
        }
}
```